# CrudRepository delete not allowed @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-hateoas

I have directly exposed repository methods with `@RequestMapping` used in `CustomRepository`. Default method provided by `CrudRepository` work fine with `@RequestMapping` except `delete(ID id)`.

Given code below

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/ces/data/reports")
@RequestMapping("/ces/data/reports")
@Api(value="reports")
public interface IReportRepository<S> extends CrudRepository<Report,Integer> {
    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(path="/delete/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    void delete(@PathVariable Integer id);
}
```

It throws an error when we run this with spring boot. 
Logs print ambiguous method delete while create bean.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'IReportRepository' method
public default void com.pb.ces.emessaging.mvp.web.repository.IReportRepository.delete(java.io.Serializable)
to {[/ces/data/reports/delete/{id}],methods=[GET]}: There is already 'IReportRepository' bean method
public abstract void com.pb.ces.emessaging.mvp.web.repository.IReportRepository.delete(java.lang.Integer) mapped.
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:567)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:531)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:241)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:213)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:183)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:125)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
        ... 50 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.overriding-sdr-response-handlers)

> Sometimes you may want to write a custom handler for a specific resource. To take advantage of Spring Data REST’s settings, message converters, exception handling, and more, use the @RepositoryRestController annotation instead of a standard Spring MVC @Controller or @RestController

So, in order to customize the delete method, you need to create a controller for example ReportRepositoryController:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class ReportRepositoryController {

    @Inject
    private IReportRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/ces/data/reports/delete/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteReport(@PathVariable Long id) {
        repository.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

And to remove the `delete` method from IReportRepository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/ces/data/reports")
@Api(value="reports")
public interface IReportRepository<S> extends CrudRepository<Report,Integer> {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[CrudRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) already exposes delete methods on this form

- void delete(ID id)  - (ID extends Serializable)
- void delete(T entity)
- void deleteAll()

so if you define  `void delete(@PathVariable Integer id);` it will report error.

One way defining another signature would be wrap inside another rest controller